# Is there any benefit of processing request at Apache (using Server side directives) Vs AEM Publisher (using Sightly conditions)?

Tags: apache, aem

In my project, there are examples were components uses Server Side directives to say include/exclude components. And few places, proper sightly/JSP code is used for same purpose. For example:

```
<c:if test="${authorMode}">
    <cq:include path="headerpar" resourceType="foundation/components/iparsys"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not authorMode}">
    <!--#include virtual="/content/myapp/${lang}/global/customer/header.html"--
</c:if>
```

From basics I understand Server Side directives gets resolved at Apache itself whereas Sightly/Handlebar codes is processed at Publisher. Is there a benefit of coding using directives? If yes, then pretty much lot of code can be moved to server side scripting since it reduces another layer and Apache is far far faster compared to publisher? Why does Adobe promote their scripts and not promote writing with server side directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSI includes are resolved on apache while cq:include within CQ. Using SSI's require from you a bit more knowledge so you know what you're doing

You can benefit from using SSI includes in many ways (mainly performance-wise as you suggested) if you use it properly.

1. Assume you have a header and footer that is the same for every page but contains heavy logic (navigation, crx tree traversing etc). In this case, if you properly configure your dispatcher caching the header will actually get rendered only once (for the first page) and if user requests another page that has the same header it will simply be fetched from dispatcher cache
2. Assuming you have a mainly brochureware page but some components that are dynamic you can also cache parts of the page and deny caching for others - again you have to properly configure your dispatcher
3. Assuming you have user specific content you could also cache parts of pages and dynamically render only parts of those (that's what Sling Dynamic Include is for -> https://github.com/Cognifide/Sling-Dynamic-Include)

So I would definitely use SSI includes for specific fragments of pages that are reused all across your site or meant to differ for different users, like some headers, footers or sth like "Welcome user 'ABC'". I would though not do that with regular content as it will just be cached within the pages html.